# VLC accesses NFS share but cannot play videos

Tags: vlc

The NFS share (configured as read-only) was added via the 'Local Network' option in the VLC app.

The NFS share's directory and contents are displayed in the VLC app; however, when a video is selected, a "Playback error" results.  Unfortunately, the error message is displayed for a fraction of a second, and is therefore illegible.

The NFS share is accessed via multiple computers, which employ the desktop version of VLC to play videos, so the share is functioning correctly.  When copies of the videos are in local storage, they play without issue.

Why are the videos unplayable?

UPDATE: Audio files contained in the NFS share are able to be played without issue.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. You should follow the following steps: [VLC Android Report bugs](https://wiki.videolan.org/Android_Report_bugs/)

Comment: Q: are you doing NFS4 only or with support of NFS3 (and maybe NFS2) as well?

Answer (score 0):

Was stuck on same issue with NFS server on macOS (native system server, not from third party tools) and VLC on Google TV installed from Google Play.

For me helped moving file from `/Users/my-user/Movies/some-other.folder.WithMany_different_specialSYMBOLS/some-movie-file.mkv` to `/Users/my-user/Movies/some-movie-file.mkv`. IDK why it's matters — maybe some stupid limitation for characters or filename limit — but it works now.